# Tkinter - NameError: name 'TopLevel' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use the TopLevel widget to create a sub window. 
However I am getting this error when I attempt to use it:

```
NameError: name 'TopLevel' is not defined
```

I'm using Python 3.6, but I've tried this on 3.5 as well with the same result. 
I am importing Tkinter with:

```
from tkinter import *
```

but I also tried

```
import tkinter as tk
```

And here's the rest of the relevant code:

```
def __init__(self):
   self.root = Tk()
   self.teams = []

def createTeamWindows(self):
    teamOneWindow = TopLevel(self.root)
    teamOneWindow.title(self.teams[0].name)
```

Comment: It's spelled `Toplevel`, not `TopLevel`.

Comment: Thank you! I feel really silly now...

Comment: @jasonharper your comment was the correct answer for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call the import name, if you don't, how will python find it? like this, look:

> edit
>   as @jasonharper also said, is **Toplevel**

```
import tkinter as tk

def createTeamWindows(self):
    teamOneWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
    teamOneWindow.title(self.teams[0].name)
```

And that's all :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately I'm now getting the error: AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'TopLevel'

Comment: @BenSpencer I fall in the same error too, look the updated answer, thanks to user jasonharper